# Trouble adding label to axes in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this code and I can't seem to create labels for the axes. I've tried copying what other scripts do but my knowledge of D3 is pretty lacking.

In particulare I was trying to merge this code with what I have to disasterous results:

```
svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Temperature (ºF)");
```

And what I have:

```
svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "x axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
   .call(xAxis)
   .append("text")
   .attr("class", "label")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
   .attr("y", -5)
   .style("text-anchor", "end")
   .text("Frequency");
```

Here is the [bl.ocks.org link](http://bl.ocks.org/pebblexe/98df91844e0d553abc3e0afeea3994de)

And here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/pebblexe/98df91844e0d553abc3e0afeea3994de)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your label is here in the DOM at the position you specified. You just need to style it to make it visible:

```
svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "x axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
   .call(xAxis)
       .append("text")
       .attr("class", "label")
       .attr("fill", "black") // <= Here
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
       .attr("y", -5)
       .style("text-anchor", "end")
       .text("Frequency");
```

Or simply use CSS:

```
.label {
  fill: black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was indeed the issue.